# how to use image in jquery-confirm js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am using alert box with jquery-confirm js. when i using text in content its working fine but when i use image in content **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js'></script><script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.js'></script><script>
    $.dialog({
        columnClass: 'col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3',
        containerFluid: true,
        title: 'Thank you!',
        content: '<img src='images/icons/success_icon.png'> for confirming the details. You will be notified with latest IPO issuance details',
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Try replacing content string with the following  " content: \`<img src="images/icons/success_icon.png"> for confirming the details. You will be notified with latest IPO issuance details\`, "

Comment: not working @AkhilAravind

Comment: can you share the updated code block ?

Comment: Its not allowing put special character

Comment: echo "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js'></script><script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.js'></script><script>
 $.dialog({
  
  title: 'Thank you!',
  content: `<img src="images/icons/success_icon.png"> for confirming the details. You will be notified with latest IPO issuance details`, 
 });
 </script>";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the working snippet, you have to use tild instead of quotes.

Take a look at template literals for more details. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
var $= jQuery;
    $.dialog({
        columnClass: 'col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3',
        containerFluid: true,
        title: 'Thank you!',
        content: `<img src="images/icons/success_icon.png"> for confirming the details. You will be notified with latest IPO issuance details`,
    });
```

```html
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.js'></script>
```